# Can i change layout of an specific QComboBox item?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qcombobox

I need to add an item to my comboBox that will be different from the others. For example, my different item will be blue and the others will be grey. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for it:

comboBox->setItemData(indexItem, QBrush(QColor(102, 162, 216, 255)), Qt::BackgroundColorRole);